# error: Application not installed

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I have build and application which is so simple. when i install that apk in virtual device, it installed successfully and run as it should be. But when i install the same APK (signed apk) in mobile device, it give the error `"Application not installed"`. I have downloaded NDK and give its path in project structure as well. Application is working properly in virtual device but not installing in real device. 
help!

Thanks in advance.

Following is the console output when i run application on virtual device.

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]

    Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
    Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
    :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:checkDebugManifest
    :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2600Alpha1Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72600Alpha1Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportConstraintConstraintLayout102Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2600Alpha1Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2600Alpha1Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2600Alpha1Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2600Alpha1Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2600Alpha1Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42600Alpha1Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2600Alpha1Library
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds1104Library
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite1104Library
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1104Library
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1104Library
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesClearcut1104Library
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGass1104Library
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet1104Library
    :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1104Library
    :app:prepareDebugDependencies
    :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugRenderscript
    :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugResources
    :app:mergeDebugResources
    :app:processDebugManifest
    :app:processDebugResources
    :app:generateDebugSources
    :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestEspressoEspressoCore222Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestEspressoEspressoIdlingResource222Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestExposedInstrumentationApiPublish05Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestRules05Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestRunner05Library
    :app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
    :app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
    :app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies

    BUILD SUCCESSFUL

    Total time: 18.303 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the same apk that run on your device and as on virtual?
Relese is stricter in some respects than  debug,
google next and find if it work
`android {
        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }`}

Comment: yes it is the same APK. its installing on virtual device and application running fine. but not on real device. it just give error "application not installed"

Comment: 1.uninstall the existed one, and reinstall
2.jniLibs  contain some  incompatible .so file

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure instance run in android studio is disabled**.

if Instant Run is activated this causes some classes to be moved. 
To disable **Instant Run** **Go to File -> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment ->Instant Run -> uncheck "Enable instant run"**

It worked for me.
I hope it will help your problem.

Nice to help you!

Comment: i tried, still same error. working in virtual device but not on real device. "application not installed"